# Why is PCRE grep treating forward slashes as whitespace?

Tags: grep, pcre, regex-lookarounds, positive-lookbehind

On bash, I'm trying to get the uppercase letter immediately after a whitespace (`A` from `File A.jpg`).

```
echo "Path/To/File A.jpg" | grep -oP '[A-Z](?!/s)'
```

This is a negative lookahead `(?!` that should return any uppercase after a whitespace. So, it should return only `A`. However, it's returning all upercases:

```
P
T
F
A
```

It seems it's treating forward slashes as whitespaces? Why? How can I get only the last `A`?

Comment: I suggest `'(?<= )[A-Z]'` or `' \K[A-Z]'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should return any uppercase after a whitespace

No, that’s not what it says at all. It says “any uppercase not followed by forward slash and s.” Well *none* of them are followed by that. So you get all the uppercase characters.

What you want is a positive lookbehind.

```
(?<=\s)[A-Z]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using grep with `-P` you can match a horizontal whitespace char using `\h` and, as also pointed out in the comments, you can use `\K` to clear the match buffer and then match a single uppercase char A-Z.

```
echo "Path/To/File A.jpg" | grep -oP '\h\K[A-Z]'
```

Output

```
A
```